# Solving $x^2 \equiv 140 \pmod{221}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm stuck with the last part of this question: solve $x^2 \equiv 140 \pmod{221}$.

We know that $140 = 7 \times2^2\times5$ and $221 = 13 \times 17$.

We split the original congruence in two, so we have:

$x^2 \equiv 140 \pmod{13}$

$x^2 \equiv 140 \pmod{17}$

Applying the properties of moduli we have:

$x^2 \equiv 10\pmod{13} \rightarrow x=\pm6$

$x^2 \equiv 4\pmod{17}  \rightarrow x=\pm2$

After this point, it's not clear for me how I can arrive to the complete solution. Any advice?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019723/number-of-solutions-in-quadratic-congruence

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2984599/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2984599/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. For instance, let $x\in\mathbb Z$ be such that $x\equiv6\pmod{13}$ and that $x\equiv-2\pmod{17}$. Since $13$ and $17$ are coprime, there are integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $13\alpha+17\beta=1$. Using the generalized Euclid algorithm, you get that, for instance, $1=4\times13-3\times17$. Therefore,$$8=6-(-2)=32\times13-24\times17.$$So,$$6-32\times13=-2-24\times17(=-410).$$So, take this number: $-410$. Or, better still, take $32$ ($-410\equiv32\pmod{221}$).

Comment: Thanks, very clear. So with the CRT I can combine the final solutions to obtain the desired answer. I must pass for the Euclide algorithm or there are other methods?

Comment: I think that using the Euclid algorithm is the natural way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I think there is a 22 in the place of 32, a typing issue

Comment: @Alessar I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: If I use 6 and 2, and I proceed, I obtain $6-2 = 4 = 17(-12)+13(16)$. This is reordered in $6+12(17)=2+13(16)=210 \equiv -11 (\mod 221) $. I was expecting 19 and not -11, maybe I miss something?

Comment: From $6-2=17\times(-12)+13\times16$, you should have deduced that $$6-13\times16=2+17\times(-12)=-202\equiv9\pmod{221}.$$

Comment: It's clear, José a typing error 9 is 19 I suppose. Thanks it's clear now, I must use the sign info for the deduction

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$x^2 -140\equiv x^2 -140-221=x^2−19^2=(x-19)(x+19)\pmod{221}.$$
It follows that 
$$x\equiv \pm 19\equiv \pm 6 \pmod{13}\quad\text{and}\quad x\equiv \pm 19\equiv \pm 2 \pmod{17}.$$ Hence we have four solutions (actually we already have two of them, i.e. $19$ and $-19$) that can be obtained by using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem):
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 6 \pmod{13}\\
x\equiv 2 \pmod{17}
\end{cases}\quad
\begin{cases}x\equiv 6 \pmod{13}\\
x\equiv -2 \pmod{17}
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}x\equiv -6 \pmod{13}\\
x\equiv 2 \pmod{17}
\end{cases}\quad
\begin{cases}x\equiv -6 \pmod{13}\\
x\equiv -2 \pmod{17}
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. By the first remark, $\pm 19$ are two solutions and all you need is to solve just ONE system:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 6 \pmod{13}\\
x\equiv -2 \pmod{17}
\end{cases}$$
if $m$ is the solution then the fourth one is $-m$.

Comment: I think I can, it's like solving a diophantine equation for each combination. Thanks for the answer, wish I could give two "correct answer" flag instead of one

Comment: @Alessar Actually here we have to solve just ONE system because, by the first remark, $\pm 19$ are two solutions and the fourth one is the opposite of the first one . As regards the flag, don't worry, I am fine with your choice.

Comment: thanks, you guys are so prepared and professional. Ok so $\pm 19$  are two solutions, and another one will be the solution of the other two system. The absolute values are two but specular, so 4 systems, 2 requested for the final solution

Comment: @Alessar I edited my answer with a P.S. have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks again! Have a nice day too!

Comment: Dear downvoter, what's the problem with my answer? If there is something wrong please help me to improve it.